# How to replace a null value with previous non-null value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to replace a null value with previous non-null value using MySQL.
I tried this:

```
SELECT
`Date_Column`
,CASE
WHEN `Value_Column` is null 
THEN (
      SELECT 
        `Value_Column` 
      FROM 
        table_name t2 
      WHERE 
        `Date_Column` = (
                         SELECT 
                           MAX(`Date_Column`) 
                         FROM 
                           table_name t3 
                         WHERE 
                           `Date_Column` < t1.`Date_Column` 
                           AND `Value_Column` > 0
                         )
      ) 
  ELSE `Value_Column`
  END AS `Value_Column`
  FROM
  table_name t1
```

This works but takes really long for big datasets. 
I tried this for a subset of data and it worked.
Is there an easier/more efficient way to achieve the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You should also explain the logic your are using to fill in the value.

Comment: Run the query with `EXPLAIN` and show us the results. Also tell us on how many records it is slow and what is the subset

Comment: `= 0` is not the same as `IS NULL`.  do you really mean NULL or do you really mean 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query to:

```
SELECT t1.Date_Column
       (CASE WHEN t1.Value_Column = 0 
             THEN (SELECT t2.Value_Column 
                   FROM table_name t2 
                   WHERE t2.Date_Column < t1.Date_Column AND t2.Value_Column > 0
                   ORDER BY t2.Date_Column DESC
                   LIMIT 1
                  )
              ELSE t2.Value_Column
        END) AS Value_Column
FROM table_name t1;
```

This is an improvement on your query because it removes the second nested subquery.  But it will still be slow.  An index on `table_name(Date_Column, Value_Column)` *might* help.

Comment: Would `AND external_table.value_column = 0` help in the sub query?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, your first check should be that your take is correctly indexed by the date column (and the value column as a covering index). If it is, then you could use the following slightly simplified query.

Note, this replaces NULL as per your description, where yours replaced 0 contrary to your description, you should be clear as to Exactly which behaviour you want.

```
SELECT
    date_column,
    COALESCE(
        value_column,
        (
            SELECT lookup.value_column
              FROM table_name AS lookup
             WHERE lookup.date_column < table_name.date_column
               AND lookup.value_column IS NOT NULL
               AND table_name.value_column IS NULL
          ORDER BY lookup.date_column DESC
             LIMIT 1
        )
    ) 
FROM
    table_name
```

(on my phone, so please forgive typos)